# Search form sample pattern

Tags: php, object-oriented, search, form

I've just started to practice coding in OOP and just wanted to ask if my code's pattern is correct.  I need your comments or suggestions so I can improve it.

**sample_class.php:**

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'sample_db';
$user = 'sample_user';
$pass = 'sample_password';
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);  

Class MySearchClass {

    public function __construct(PDO $conn) {
        $this->pdo=$conn;  
    }

    public function search_name($keyword){

        $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = '$keyword'";  
        $result = $this->pdo->prepare($query);  
        $result ->execute();  

        return $result;
    }

    public function view_all(){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM table";  
        $result = $this->pdo->prepare($query);  
        $result ->execute();  

        return $result;
    } 
}
```

**search_form.php:**

```
<?php  
include('sample_class.php');
$search= new MySeachClass($database_connection);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){  
    $keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
    $go_search = $search->search_name($keyword);

    $data = $go_search->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   

    foreach($data as $row){
        echo $row['name'];  
        echo other rows....
    }  

}else{
    $view = $search->view_all();
    $data = $view->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  

    foreach($data as $row){
        echo $row['name'];  
        echo other rows....
    }
}

<form action="" method="POST">  
<input type="text" name="keyword">  
<input type="submit" name="search">
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a recommendation to bind parameters correctly. This sort of thing is used to prevent against SQL injection attacks.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = :keyword";  
$statement = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
$statement->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result $statement->execute();
```

Read more about [PDOStatement#bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) here

Answer (score 3):

The caller of `MySearchClass` methods should not know that there is a PDO access layer to database - the caller should not know about database at all! The class might internally query cache first or return hardcoded values - but return ready to use php collections (arrays)!

So I suggest moving all the `fetchAll` calls into `MySearchClass` methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on PHP 5.2.0 you should also use [filter_input_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php) or [filter_input()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) rather than $_POST as this allows you to sanitize the string before it goes anywhere else.

For example:

```
$post_copy = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

or

```
$keyword = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'keyword', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

Using the filter_input_array can also allow you to specify what items you expect in the $_POST as items and apply a filter on them. This basically means if someone sends junk to you in the $_POST it will also be filtered out.